# When and where is calling menu_link_save safe and appropriate?

Tags: 7, routes

From what hooks (or "types" of hooks) is it appropriate to call [menu_link_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/7)?

I have a situation where I would like to add a bunch of entries to `{menu_links}` where an entry already exists in `{menu_router}`.  To state this another way, I would like to add direct links to a menu for which another module has defined a wildcard entry via [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7).

A concrete example would be that I would like to add a menu item to a menu for "taxonomy/term/123".  In this case, there is already a router entry for "taxonomy/term/%" which the taxonomy module created.

I know how to use this function.  I am just not sure where I can (or should) call this from.  This isn't a situation where a user is saving a node, or something else that would be considered an event.  Essentially, I just want my module to create a bunch of links so the end user doesn't have to.

Would this be best done by a [hook_enable](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_enable/7)?  Are there any popular modules that I can take a look at for examples / use cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, hook_enable() sounds correct.

To find examples, on way is look at what's using the function on [drupalcontrib.org](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal--includes--menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/7).  That points to [menu_enable()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal--modules--menu--menu.module/function/menu_enable/7), which is even a core function.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping to find more examples, but this does seem proper.  I ended up doing this, and also adding an admin menu entry to check/rebuild the additions for when things get messed up.